# Matlab slider when Min=Max=Value=1

Tags: matlab, slider, matlab-guide

I use a slider to browse through a collection whose size changes dynamically and can very well be 1.

But if I:

```
set(mySld, 'min', 1, 'max', 1, 'value', 1, 'sliderstep', [1 1])
```

The slider will look like this, with the so-called thumb half as long as the "trough":

[image: wrong slider]

Which is not okay, because if you then click on the left side of the slider, the value will be set to zero, i.e. out of range, and the slider simply disappears.

Am I using wrong property settings?

(of course, I could `set(mySld, 'enable', 'off')` whenever Min=Max=1, but it feels like a hack).

Comment: What version of Matlab do you use? With ML2013a i can not reproduce that behaviour: `Warning: slider control requires that Min be less than Max
Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid 
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener to check for the value against the min and/or max:

```
figure; 
% create the uicontrol
sl = uicontrol ( 'style', 'slider', 'min', 1, 'max', 1, 'value', 1, 'sliderstep', [1 1]);
% create a listener to check the value are reset appropriately
addlistener ( sl, 'Value', 'PostSet', @(obj,event)set ( sl, 'Value', max(sl.Min,  min(sl.Value,sl.Max))) );
```